# $L \log L$-convexity in $L^{1,\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

It can be shown that the Lorentz space $L^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (also called *weak* $L^1$) is not normable and exhibits a lack of convexity. Namely, there exist a sequence $(u_n)\subseteq L^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of nonnegative functions and a sequence of real numbers $\lambda_n>0$ such that $\|u_n\|_{1,\infty}\le 1$, $\sum\lambda_n<\infty$, $\sum \lambda_n u_n\not\in L^{1,\infty}$.

I read without reference that, however, there is a sort of $L\log L$-convexity:

> if $(u_n)\subseteq L^{1,\infty}$ is a bounded sequence, $\lambda_n>0$
>   and $\sum|\lambda_n|(1+|\log\lambda_n|)<\infty$ (or equivalently
>   $\lambda_n\to 0$ and $\sum|\lambda_n\log\lambda_n|<\infty$), then
>   $\sum\lambda_n u_n\in L^{1,\infty}$

(meaning that the partial sums converge in the topology of $L^{1,\infty}$). Where can I find a proof of this fact?